# How to create VIew of ViewModel, where ViewModel is an IEnumerable with two strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have been working on an MVC ViewModel that contains scalar data values I need to pass to the View (instead of using ViewBags) along with an IEnumerable that contains the tabular data that goes in the table. This was based on a suggestion someone made on an earlier SO question. This way, there is no duplication I would have if I added the scalar values as constants to a table that could have many, many rows.

I am pasting my (simplified) data model and view model definitions and the controller action in question. The data structures are what I need it to be, but Visual Studio won't create a View from this Action (right-click and select "Add View with Model").

My question, is given the Action and Model definitions, what do I need to do so that I can create a View of the View Model?

I'm figuring auto-scaffold is out of the question because the ViewModel has no key, so I'm expecting manual coding. I have no idea how to do this, because all the examples I've seen show ViewModels that are essentially the equivalent of merging two tables into a larger table.

I have tried using @model = [ViewModelName] and @model = IEnumerable, but both failed.

The binary response would be, "Duh, the error is telling you exactly what's going on. You don't have a Key."  But that response doesn't help me resolve this. How do I move forward with *this* definition of the ViewModel and create a  View?

**View Model**

```
public class StudentRosterViewModel
{        
    // This list is the "table" shown on the view
    public IEnumerable<StudentRoster> StudentRosters { get; set; }

    // These are scalar values apply to the view as a whole
    public string SelectedCampus { get; set; }
    public string SelectedFiscalYear { get; set; }
}
```

**Data Model**

```
[Table("StudentRoster")]
public partial class StudentRoster
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Campus { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string FiscalYear { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]        
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public int StudentID { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Action:**

```
public ActionResult FilterableIndex(string campus="MRA",string fiscalYear = "FY16")
{       
    StudentRosterViewModel vm = new StudentRosterViewModel();

    // this is tabular data and goes in the "table"
    vm.StudentRosters = db.StudentRosters
        .Where(m => m.Campus == campus)
        .Where(m => m.FiscalYear == fiscalYear)
        .ToList();

    // These are scalar values; they are not tabular
    // These are needed to supply values to jQuery 
    vm.SelectedCampus = campus;
    vm.SelectedFiscalYear = fiscalYear;

    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Action your "FilterableIndex", it is HttpPost Or Get, using json or request from

Comment: You passing an instance of `StudentRosterViewModel` to the view so the view needs `@model StudentRosterViewModel` and then to generate your table, `@foreach(var item in Model.StudentRosters) { ....`

Comment: Note also it needs to be `return View(vm);` in order to return the model to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke -- you caught me during another iteration, I had View(vm) in there before...

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge I think your bug is you don't setting key for tableModel, you need add attribute "[Key]" on property  public int ID { get; set; }

Comment: Success!  Thank you StephenMuecke and LinhTuan for your suggestions. The key was adding a Key to the ViewModel class and giving it a value of 1 in the Controller (it's only one row). Visual Studio then created an Empty Page with Model, and I was able to then see my Model properties. So that there is a one-to-one answer to my question, I'll post my working code -- after a break. If you'd like submit any further thoughts or (I wouldn't do it _that_ way) ideas, I'd love to see what you think, so I can make sounder code.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge, A a view model should never contain a property marked with `[Key]`. That is a EF data model specific attribute and has nothing to do with view models. And as Scott Hannen has noted, your view models should be in a separate folder.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take out key from viewmodel class and see if it helps.

Comment: I just posted my answer -- any further ideas to make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is that in your Views folder there's a folder corresponding to the name of your controller. For example, if the controller is `StudentRosterController` then the folder would be named `StudentRoster`.

Then the view would correspond to the name of the action - `FilterableIndex.cshtml`.

The .cshtml file would begin with

```
@model MvcApp.Controllers.StudentRosterViewModel
```

(Where MvcApp.Controllers is the namespace that contains your model.)

Comment: Thank you. That's also helpful. Just as you posted, I finally hit the Eureka moment -- this is part of the answer. I'll be posting my answer in about an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of everyone in the comments (@StephenMuecke, @LinhTuan) and @ScottHannen, I am able to create a working and improved View page of the ViewModel.

Here are the structural improvements I made.

1. I created a ViewModels folder and placed the ViewModel class there (no longer in the Models folder).
2. I took out the `[Key]` attribute and Id property from the ViewModel -- it really wasn't what made it appear to work before.
3. I right-clicked the Action Name and selected "Create View" (empty without model)
4. The View was successfully created. The View code you see below is a basic test for ability access the ViewModel properties and display data -- I can add Bootstrap styles and the functionality, now that I have a basic test.
5. The IEnumerable took a little work to unpack. I later learned how to add a variable `var headerMeta = Model.StudentRosters.FirstOrDefault();` so that I could use `@Html.DisplayNameFor` in the table body section, I picked up another trick `(modelItem => item.[column name])`.
6. A potential further step is to create a custom DisplayFor and DisplayNameFor helper so that I can more directly use the Html helpers without having to add the `headerMeta` variable.

I call this an initial success because I finally have data reaching the view.

> ```
> @model ViewModelTest.Controllers.ViewModels.StudentRosterViewModel
>
> @{
>     ViewBag.Title = "FilterableIndex";
>     @*This enables us to read the StudentRoster column names*@
>     var headerMeta = Model.StudentRosters.FirstOrDefault();
> }
>
> <h2>FilterableIndex</h2>
>
> <p>Test for reception of data</p>
> <ul>
>     <li>Selected campus: @Model.SelectedCampus</li>
>     <li>Selected fiscal year: @Model.SelectedFiscalYear</li>
> </ul>
>
> @*I'll add bootstrap styles later*@
> <table>
>     <tr>
>         <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => headerMeta.Campus)</th>
>         <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => headerMeta.FiscalYear)</th>
>         <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => headerMeta.StudentName)</th>
>         <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => headerMeta.StudentID)</th>
>     </tr>     
> @foreach (var item in Model.StudentRosters)
> {    
>     <tr>        
>         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Campus)</td>
>         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FiscalYear)</td>
>         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentName)</td>
>         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentID)</td>
>     </tr>
> }
> ```